Create list of unique dataset combinations of duplicate removal
I have a dataset with duplicates across groups.
For instance:
dat <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C","C","C"),
  values = c("duplicate1","duplicate2",3,"duplicate1",
             5,"duplicate1","duplicate2",6)
)

My expected output is a list of N datasets of unique combinations of how the duplicates can be kept by each group:
dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6)
dfs[[1]] ## Combination 1

  group      values
1    A duplicate1
2    A duplicate2
3    A          3
4    B          5
5    C          6

dfs[[2]] ## Combination 2

  group      values
1    A duplicate2
2    A          3
3    B          5
4    B duplicate1
5    C          6

dfs[[3]] ## Combination 3

  group      values
1    A duplicate2
2    A          3
3    B          5
4    C          6
5    C duplicate1

dfs[[4]] ## Combination 4

  group      values
1    A duplicate1
2    A          3
3    B          5
4    C          6
5    C duplicate2

dfs[[5]] ## Combination 5

  group      values
1    A          3
2    B          5
3    B duplicate1
4    C          6
5    C duplicate2

dfs[[6]] ## Combination 6

  group      values
1    A          3
2    B          5
3    C          6
4    C duplicate1
5    C duplicate2


I thought I had a solution:
Find all unique combinations of removing a duplicate in groups from a data set
However, this solution does not work if the duplicate is across > 2 groups, as in the above example. It will only remove one of the duplicates from the dataframe, and combinations will then for instance have kept duplicate1 in group B or C as well.

Can you describe more what you mean by "how duplicates can be kept across groups"? For your sample input, what is the total length of results you are looking for? Since duplicate1 has 3 occurrences and duplicate2 has 2 occurrences, should the result list have length 3 choose 1 * 2 choose 1 = 6? Is that logic right?

Good evening Gregor Thomas. Yes, exactly. I have now posted the full expected output. Six combinations. What is difficult is that duplicate1 is in group A, B and C, and in the output it may only be kept in one of them.

Seem like a minor adaptation of this question. I don't have time to write an answer now, but I can take a look again in a few hours if no one else has answered yet.

library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  summarise(group = list(group), .by = values) %>% 
  {apply(expand.grid(.$group), 1, \(x) 
         data.frame(group = x, values = .$values, row.names = NULL) %>% 
           arrange(group))}

#> [[1]]
#>   group     values
#> 1     A duplicate1
#> 2     A duplicate2
#> 3     A          3
#> 4     B          5
#> 5     C          6
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   group     values
#> 1     A duplicate2
#> 2     A          3
#> 3     B duplicate1
#> 4     B          5
#> 5     C          6
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   group     values
#> 1     A duplicate2
#> 2     A          3
#> 3     B          5
#> 4     C duplicate1
#> 5     C          6
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>   group     values
#> 1     A duplicate1
#> 2     A          3
#> 3     B          5
#> 4     C duplicate2
#> 5     C          6
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>   group     values
#> 1     A          3
#> 2     B duplicate1
#> 3     B          5
#> 4     C duplicate2
#> 5     C          6
#> 
#> [[6]]
#>   group     values
#> 1     A          3
#> 2     B          5
#> 3     C duplicate1
#> 4     C duplicate2
#> 5     C          6

Created on 2024-04-22 with reprex v2.0.2

It works like a charm M, thank you.
If I had other columns in the dataset, that were attached to the "values". Am I able to keep these values in the current code somehow? Or should I make a second step with a lapply/loop and a merge/join code?

This seems to work. Not sure if there is a more elegant way of doing it:
dat.list <- lapply(combos, function(x)   x %>%      left_join(y = dat, by = join_by(group, values)) ) 
Thanks again!
